# Socket.io not working with external access without express

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

My question is am i possible to run the socket.io lib without using express? The thing is i want to make node as an external web socket server which just receives sockets connection and callbacks and just simply reply to them, not to make own routes or send page view (I'm using codeigniter for that work).

My current test app is like this on Server:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
 console.log('A new socket has joined: ' + socket.id);
 var tweet = {user: "nodesource", text: "Hello, world!"};

// to make things interesting, have it send every second
var interval = setInterval(function () {
  socket.emit("tweet", tweet);
}, 1000);

 socket.on("disconnect", function () {
  clearInterval(interval);
 });
});
```

On Client:

```
<script>
const socket = io('http://localhost:4000/node_server');


socket.on('disconnect',function(){
    alert('Im not connected, server is down');
});

socket.on("tweet", function(tweet) {
// todo: add the tweet as a DOM node
console.log("tweet from", tweet.username);
console.log("contents:", tweet.text);
});
```

My problem is that i have tested with express the chat example of socket.io and it works ofc but they use route and send the page and in my case i just want my other external page to communicate with node and not node sending me the page. Basically when i trigger some emit or function at server or client it does not fire just on server the connection but nothing else (p.s: also used io.sockets.on and doesn't work too)
If anyone has passed this and knows what my problem might be, i'll be glad.

Comment: If you're setting up this application as a separate application does it really matter what server software you are using? Also why are you listening to `http://localhost:4000/node_server` instead of `http://localhost:4000` ? A plain http server would be a pain imo.

Comment: Because the actual client is a index.html located in another folder and the node_server is actually where the index.js and node modules are to be able to start the server. The thing is not that, the thing is that the sockets connect and you see the event fired on the console of node meaning that the socket is connected in the server-side but it does not fire client connect function nor the callbacks i put there and i had already tested few

Comment: The folder/file of client is in the same host but soon it will be different hosts but the thing is not the path, is really that the triggers doesn't work when i have a stable connection

Comment: Another thing, the client socket.connected returns false meaning that the socket is not connected but in the server it registers and triggers on connection so i can't get what's happening

Comment: I think there might be some confusion but, from what I can gather it sounds like you just want to separate the client from server because they're hosted on two different machines. Is this the case? If so, I can write up a quick example for you.

Comment: Yes basically the thing is that i'm using a MVC framework (php) which will return the view and i don't want express to do that dirty work for me so in my view i want to add a script which connects to the external server which just receive and send data trough the sockets (as a server, with node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay let's start off with something really basic here is our express server which is only hosting our socket application:

```
var app = require("express")();
var server = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Server listening at port %d", port);
});

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  console.log("A new socket has joined: " + socket.id);

  socket.on("hello", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

You already understand that much but, it's important to note that this server will listen for any socket connections from any address. This is important to keep in mind.

Now let's look at the client html file

```
<html>

<body>
    <button id="hiBtn">Say Hi to your server</button>
    <!-- You only need to include the client file here -->
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/socketio/socket.io-client/master/dist/socket.io.js" </script>
    </script>
    <script>
        const serverLocation = "localhost:4000" // or whatever your server location is
        const socket = io(serverLocation);

        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById("hiBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
                socket.emit("hello", "Hi there, this is the client speaking");
            })
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Notice how I do not have `<script src="/socket/socket.io">` this is because this html file is being hosted on a completely separate client. You need to simply include the client socket.io file here which is usually located in `node_modules\socket.io-client\dist\socket.io.js` if you installed it via NPM. Or you can use the url I provided in my example. Just make sure that `serverLocation` points to your express server and you're all set.

P.S. for this example I tested it by hosting the html file on port:5000 and the express server on port:4000 if you were curious.

Comment: It's not that what i'm looking, that does what every single doc example shows about the client and server being in diff folder or whatever. I don't want to use express because i have my php hosting the views and those views have a script to connect to IO. for example my php view is in http://localhost/platform/index.html and my node is in http://localhost/node_server and so that's why i was trying to connect with port :4000 for that folder specificly

Comment: It was the mentioning of the folder on the connect URL